# angularjs create dynamic divs based on click and calculate in rows totals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, sum, angular-ngmodel

I have a to dynamically create rows with some values(fixed values) in it and i want to show this values and the SUM of this values for EACH row.
Then i want to update some of this values and see that also my SUM change:

here is my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="containerEsterno" class="row m-lg border-bottom">
    <button ng-click="vm.add()">New Item</button>
    <br>
    <div class="row m-xs" id="containerInterno">
        <label>question</label>
        <label>text</label>
        <label>checkbox</label>
        <label>addendo1</label>
        <label>addendo2</label>
        <label>risultato</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="containerInterno" ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        <input ng-model="item.question" type="text">
        <input ng-model="item.text" type="text" >
        <input ng-model="item.inlineChecked" type="checkbox" >
        <input ng-model="item.addendo1" type="number" >
        <input ng-model="item.addendo2" type="number" >
        <input ng-model="item.risultato" ng-value="item.addendo1+item.addendo2" class="colonnasmall">
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my JavaScript:

```
this.add = function() {
      vm.items.push({ 
          inlineChecked: false,
          question: "",
          text: "",
          addendo1 : 1,
          addendo2 : 2,
          risultato: addendo1+addendo2,
    });
  };
```

but this give me the error:
*ReferenceError: risultato is not defined.....*

i changed then risultato to be=0 (on javascript),

and i changed the ng-model

```
<input ng-model="item.risultato" ng-value="item.addendo1+item.addendo2" class="colonnasmall">
```

to

```
<input ng-model="item.risultato=item.addendo1+item.addendo2" class="colonnasmall">
```

it works but gave me an error:

*Error: ngModel:nonassign
Non-Assignable Expression*

anyone can help me??
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in JS (no need to add a default value):

```
this.add = function() {
  vm.items.push({ 
      inlineChecked: false,
      question: "",
      text: "",
      addendo1 : 1,
      addendo2 : 2
});
};
```

In HTML , remove ng-value naduse ng-change on both operands:

```
    <input ng-model="item.addendo1" type="number" ng-change="item.risultato = item.addendo1+item.addendo2" >
    <input ng-model="item.addendo2" type="number" ng-change="item.risultato = item.addendo1+item.addendo2" >
    <input ng-model="item.risultato"  class="colonnasmall">
```